# Display ALL keys in dataset

Tags: version-10, dataset

I created a dateset (estimates) with 25 keys (my columns), and about a hundred rows.  I'd like to be able to list the keys from the dataset.

I did this:

```
estimates[Keys]
```

which returned:

[image]

I also tried:

```
estimates[1]
```

which returned:

[image]

How can I display the entire list of keys?

My code is below:

```
Module[
{fileTemp, header, data}, 
fileTemp = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "test.xlsx", {"Sheets", "estimates"}];
header = fileTemp[[1]];
data = fileTemp[[2 ;;]];
estimates = Dataset@Map[AssociationThread[header, #] &]@data;
```

]

The following is part of the Excel sheet:

[image]

Comment: I am now curious why your command `estimates[Keys]` worked when I get an error: "Cannot apply Keys to an expression of the form {__Association}" -- would you please check to see if e.g. `titanic[Keys]` works on your system, using the definition from my answer?

Comment: I also get an error with titanic[Keys].  I checked and the syntax is the same as my estimates[Keys].  Maybe my estimates dataset is improperly formatted.  If I just type titanic I see a nicely formed table.  If I just type estimates I get what looks like the beginning of estimates // Normal.  That is it starts with {<|Business ID -> TYPR1206, .  Although that might be because I have too many keys.

Comment: So that we both might learn would you be able to upload your full dataset code somewhere, like pastebin?

Comment: I added the code and a truncated sanitized version of the Excel sheet to my question.  Does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];
```

Then:

```
titanic[1, Keys]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OR

```
Query[1, Keys] @ titanic
```

You can convert to `List` with `Normal` e.g.:

```
titanic[1, Keys] // Normal
```

> {"class", "age", "sex", "survived"}

Another variation:

```
Normal @ Keys @ titanic[[1]]
```

Comment: That only seems to work when there aren't too many keys.  I have another dataset with only 9 keys and your solution works fine there.  There doesn't seem to be an option to tell Mathematica to expand the output similar to what it does when you ask it to show you a very large list.

Comment: @Mitchell `titanic[1, Keys] // Normal` should work.  The key is `Normal` to convert to a standard `List` format.  The truncation you see without it is part of the formatting of `Dataset`.

Comment: Oh! That does make the difference.

Comment: @MitchellKaplan, just add `// Normal` at the end of both methods. See my edit.

Answer (score 6):

To get all `Keys` for a `Dataset` named `dataset`, where the first entry doesn't include all `Keys`

```
dataset[Keys /* Flatten /* Union] // Normal
```

will reveal all `Keys`, except those of nested `Association`s

Comment: This seems like the best answer but I think `Keys[#] &` may be replaced with simply `Keys`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you're correct and I changed it. But I'm surprised, that this even works for `Dataset`s where `dataset[Keys]` fails.

Comment: There are lots of bugs to be worked out.  It's quite clear that v10 was a bit rushed.

Comment: I've been using the Prefix or Postfix version of this in 10.0.1: `Normal@Union@Flatten@Keys@dataset` or `dataset//Keys//Flatten//Union//Normal`.

Comment: FWIW: Using `DeleteDuplicates` instead of `Union` preserves the ordering of the keys.

Answer (score 4):

On the example Datasets in the documentation `dataset[Keys]` fails with an error, but I believe you can use this:

```
titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];

titanic // First // Keys // Normal
```

> ```
> {"class", "age", "sex", "survived"}
> ```

I should have emphasized that the most important function here is [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Normal.html), which will convert output to a standard `List`.  This prevents the automatic formatting used for `Dataset` from truncating your output, and also lets it be handled as a common list by other functions.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks.